# Making phone call in worklight 6.2

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

In Worklight 6.0, I can easily make phone call using: `window.location="tel:12345679";`
But in Worklight 6.2, this doesn't work. in Android it will throw an error:

```
Error: The protocal isn't supported.
```

I've tried adding the CALL_PHONE permission and add the below line to config.xml, but no luck:
`<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes">`

Anybody know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<access origin="*"/>`
To `<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="true">`

Then, both of the below worked:

- In the HTML: `<a href="tel:+1-800-555-1234">call this number</a>`,
- In a function (for example, `wlCommonInit()`): `document.location.href = "tel:+375292771265";`

I'm using IBM Worklight Studio 6.2.0.01-20141015-1508 (latest version from the Eclipse Marketplace).

Related question: [How to open the phone dialer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122713/how-to-open-the-phone-dialer)

Comment: same worklight version. but still no luck here. weird.  CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-10 Description=The protocol isn't supported. URL=tel:10086

Comment: still doesn't work. can you share your whole project to me? to let me have a try? thanks. my customer is pushing.

Comment: The only change I did in my project was alter native\res\xml\config.xml -- replaced the `<access ...>` element with the one I mentioned in my answer. The only other "change" is the HTML from my answer as well. Here is the config.xml. Try again in a new project: http://pastebin.com/S03pPXvg

Comment: Thanks Idan, the key is to remove the original <access origin="*"> line. thank you very much.